# Homomorphisms from free abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is a homomorphism out of a free abelian group determined by its value at the basis elements?

Comment: Yes, as any element in the free group has *unique* expression *up to order* as a $\,\Bbb Z-$combination of those **free** basis elements.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is what free abelian groups are designed to do. In more details, if $A$ is a free abelian group on the set $S$ then, for all abelian groups $A'$ there is a natural bijection between the set of functions $f:S\to A'$ and the set of group homomorphisms $\psi: A\to A'$.

Comment: This is a dumb question, but for instance if $f$ is such a group homomorphism, then is $f(ne_i) = nf(e_i)$ or is it $f(n)f(e_i)$?

Comment: The former. $f$ is not even defined at $n$, since $n$ is an integer, and not (in general) an element of the group.